# live(click) doesn't work but live(mouseover) does

Tags: jquery, jquery-click-event

I have this code

```
    $(".subcategoryOption .image, .subcategoryOption .text").live('click', function() {
    alert("hello");
});
```

With "click" doesn't work, but with "mouseover" does.
I have tested it on http://jsfiddle.net/SW5sc/22/ and it works well, so i guess it can be a problem with the rest of my code.

Any idea about what it can be?
Thanks.

Comment: Save your fiddle before posting the url.. your link is empty. Also, what is the rest of your code?

Comment: Could you post a link to the fiddle as well as more of your code?

Comment: I've updated my post with the correct url for jsFiddle but you can not execute it as it needs more files...

Comment: Btw, my vesion is 1.7.2 for jQuery and 1.8.18 for jQueryUi

Comment: @Steve It's working on your fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have an issue with the selectors. Can you tell me what elements you pretend to find using `".subcategoryOption .image, .subcategoryOption .text"` explicitly?

Comment: I tried also with a class as a selector and it doesn't work either. Here is my jQuery code (but you can not execute it as it needs more files) http://jsfiddle.net/SW5sc/22/

Comment: when i click on the image or on the text i get the `alert('hola')`. The mouseover is also working.

Comment: i havent seen all your code, but would not be better if you leave that selector like ".subcategory", that way the text would do the fade effects on the entire div and not only when you put your mouse over the text or the image.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery recently started migrating live over to `.on` instead of `.live`.
Try

```
$(document).on('click', ".subcategoryOption .image, .subcategoryOption .text",
    function () { 
        alert("hello");
    }
);
```